# setting up history variables for ssh user

Tags: ssh, unix, history

im logging into a particular ip using

ssh user@ip
then i type in a few commands,
then i exit and when i relogin and type history, all the previous commands are gone. Now i understand i have to export my history into a HISTFILE to store it. But only these two files are available for modification : .bashrc and .bash_profile for the given user. i exported HISTFILE in both files, yet i am not able to store history. the shell i am using for this user is KORN.

the output of ls -lrta in folder /home/user on the remote server:

```
$ ls -lrta
total 40
-rw-r--r--   1 GJMEHUL GJMEHUL  120 May 11 18:20 .gtkrc
-rw-r--r--   1 GJMEHUL GJMEHUL   24 May 11 18:20 .bash_logout
drwxr-xr-x  11 root    root    4096 May 22 16:05 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 GJMEHUL GJMEHUL  235 Jun 14 16:22 .bash_profile
-rw-------   1 GJMEHUL GJMEHUL  218 Jun 14 18:10 .sh_history
-rw-r--r--   1 GJMEHUL GJMEHUL  168 Jun 14 18:16 .bashrc
-rw-r--r--   1 GJMEHUL GJMEHUL  704 Jun 14 18:17 .zshrc
-rw-------   1 GJMEHUL GJMEHUL 3293 Jun 14 18:17 .viminfo
drwx------   2 GJMEHUL GJMEHUL 4096 Jun 14 18:17 .
```

Comment: Which ksh? pdksh?

Answer (score 0):

A "normal" ksh uses `/etc/profile` and then `$HOME/.profile` - check if HISTFILE is unset in /etc/profile and/or create a $HOME/.profile and set it there.